# Aplicar diferente operación a cada columna python

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

Tengo las siguientes lineas de codigo:

```
vecmin= np.array([-449.88795501 ,-115.61304463 , -69.25102533] )
vec_max = np.array([-350.16078387  , 23.16618691 ,-812.95881925])
matrix = np.array([vec_min,vec_max])

print("---"*20)
print(diff," "*4, "std: ",np.std(matrix, axis= 0))
print("Std mejorada: ",vec_max-np.std(matrix,axis=0))
nueva_std = np.array([vecmin ,vec_max-np.std(matrix,axis=0)])
print("Calculando std new: ",np.std(nueva_std,axis=0))
print("---"*20)
```

Lo que trato de hacer es llevar el vector maximo un poco mas cerca con la diferencia de std
por ejemplo si saco la std de matrix por columna me queda un vector asi:

```
std:  [ 49.86358557  69.38961577 371.85389696]
```

EL cual me gustaria operar con vec_max a tal punto que la std sea mas pequeña lo que se me ocurrio fue hacer lo siguiente:

```
std_mejor = vec_max - np.std(matrix,axis=0)
```

por lo que si hallamos la std de vec_min y vec_mac nos queda algo asi:

```
nueva_std = np.array([vec_min ,std_mejor])
print("Calculando std new: ",np.std(nueva_std,axis=0))

Calculando std new: [ 24.93179278  34.69480788 557.78084544]
```

Como podemos observar las dos primeras std mejoraron significativamente pero paso lo contrario con la ultima debido a la convención de signos es aqui donde viene mi pregunta,
¿Que debo hacer para que al hacer la operacion matematicamente se detecte si hay que sumar o restar? ando en busca de algo que evite utilizar condicionales puesto que me toca hacer este proceso para muchos datos por lo que se tornaria un poco lento.

Respuesta esperada:

```
[ 24.93179278  34.69480788 185.92694848]
```

Nota:
Para obtener el valor de 185.... tuve que cambiar la operacion resta por una suma, aunque si hacemos esto los demas valores son los que se tornaran un poco por encima de la antigua std

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parece que lo que intentas se puede entender geométricamente como "acercar" una serie de puntos a otro dado. En este caso el punto "objetivo" es el vector `vec_min` que tiene tres elementos y puede entenderse como un punto 3D. El punto que intentamos acercar a él sería `vec_max`.

Lo que intentas "acercándolos" es reducir la desviación típica de la "nube" de puntos.

Si esta interpretación es correcta, el problema que tienes se puede entender de esta otra forma:

- Dado el punto que quiero "acercar" a `vec_min`, la heurística que usarás será sumarle (o restarle) la desviación típica.
- Hay que elegir si conviene sumar o mejor restar, con el objetivo de que el nuevo punto esté más cerca del objetivo.

Por tanto, si no queremos andar con condicionales que ralentizarían el cómputo, sino que queremos usar operaciones vectoriales de `numpy` la estrategia sería la siguiente:

- La resta `vec_min - vec_max` nos da un "vector" de la dirección en que hay que moverse.
- Cada elemento de ese vector tendrá un signo
- El signo del elemento es el que nos dice si hay que sumar o restar la desviación típica. El signo de la propia desviación no importa, por lo que podemos usar su valor absoluto.

Así que para implementar estas ideas haría lo siguiente (la línea clave es la que asigna `estrategia =` )

```
import numpy as np
vec_min = np.array([-449.88795501 ,-115.61304463 , -69.25102533] )
vec_max = np.array([-350.16078387  , 23.16618691 ,-812.95881925])
matrix = np.array([vec_min,vec_max])

print("Std inicial:", np.std(matrix, axis=0))
std = np.std(matrix, axis=0)
estrategia = (vec_max - abs(std) * np.sign(vec_max-vec_min))
print("Nuevo vec_max:", estrategia)
nueva_nube = np.array([vec_min, estrategia])
print("Nueva std: ", np.std(nueva_nube, axis=0))
```

Puedes observar cómo esta estrategia reduce la std en las tres componentes:

```
Std inicial: [ 49.86358557  69.38961577 371.85389696]
Nuevo vec_max: [-400.02436944  -46.22342886 -441.10492229]
Nueva std:  [ 24.93179278  34.69480789 185.92694848]
```

Comment: Impresionante! O: ¡Gracias! Excelente respuesta!

Answer (score 0):

Bueno intenta probar un un bucle y operar elemento con elemento

```
   std_mejorada = np.zeros_like(vec_max)
    
    for i in range(vec_max.shape[0]):
      if vec_max[i] > 0:
        std_mejorada[i] = vec_max[i] + np.std(matrix[:, i])
      else:
        std_mejorada[i] = vec_max[i] - np.std(matrix[:, i])
    
    nueva_std = np.array([vec_min ,std_mejorada])
    print("Calculando std new: ",np.std(nueva_std,axis=0))
```

El resultado debe ser como el que esperas

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).